# How do I assign multiple inline variables in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I am trying to select multiple variables from a subquery in order to use later.  Here's my code:

```
DECLARE @MarketplaceName VARCHAR(50),
    @ProductFieldID INT,
    @FromValue VARCHAR(255) = (
        SELECT mcvm.MarketplaceName,
            mcvm.ProductFieldID,
            mcvm.FromValue
        FROM [Meta].[MarketplaceCategoryValueMapping] AS mcvm
        WHERE mcvm.MarketplaceCategoryValueMappingID = @MapID
        )
```

I'm getting the following error message:

> *Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.*

I'm trying to map `@MarketplaceName` from `mcvm.MarketplaceName`, etc.

What I would like is to not have to write multiple `SELECT` statements for each of these variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you trying to do this?

```
DECLARE @MarketplaceName VARCHAR(50),
        @ProductFieldID INT,
        @FromValue VARCHAR(255)
SELECT  @MarketplaceName    = mcvm.MarketplaceName,
        @ProductFieldID     = mcvm.ProductFieldID,
        @FromValue          = mcvm.FromValue
FROM [Meta].[MarketplaceCategoryValueMapping] AS mcvm
WHERE mcvm.MarketplaceCategoryValueMappingID = @MapID
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you do it.  Also, this isn't a sub-query, it is just a query.

```
DECLARE @MarketplaceName VARCHAR(50),
        @ProductFieldID INT,
        @FromValue VARCHAR(255)


SELECT @MarketplaceName = mcvm.MarketplaceName,
       @ProductFieldID = mcvm.ProductFieldID,
       @FromValue = mcvm.FromValue
FROM [Meta].[MarketplaceCategoryValueMapping] AS mcvm
WHERE mcvm.MarketplaceCategoryValueMappingID = @MapID
```

Comment: Gotcha, I think trying to do it with a subquery was confusing me.  Thanks!